# Adding section to View dynamically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm wondering is there any way to dynamically add sections to Views in MVC?

this is what I have in mind

```
@model Foo 

@AddSections(Foo.Bar)
```

and this would be the `AddSections` Method although I know the output should not be `string`.

```
public string AddSections(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 1 :
            return "@section State1 { <h1>Hello World! </h1>}" ;
        default :
            return "@section State2 { <h1>See you, World! </h1>}" ;        
    }
}
```

So in a more simple words my question is

**What should the output of this method be to render as sections in View.**

Comment: You can see [Dynamically Defined Content Sections in Razor Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347596/dynamically-defined-content-sections-in-razor-views).

Comment: @alisoltani I have already seen that question. It's not exactly what I'm looking for. this link uses a solution to somehow substitute sections , but I need them to stay on page and get called by SharedLayout via RenderSection

Comment: You can almost copy your AddSections code directly to the view.  Razor can have pretty much C# code directly in it, and will output the correct HTML at runtime.

Comment: @Neil I know I could surround my section in razor with an if statement, but for the reasons I don't want to do that.

Comment: So, @Arvin, you want to go from a type-safe (ish) method with intellisense, to a non-typesafe, non-intellisense method that is harder to write?  I'd say that's the wrong solution.  I hope you aren't planning going to store these Sections in a database...

Comment: @Neil I'm not planning to do such a thing. I'm just wondering if MVC has anything to support this. I know it's not the best idea.